# Проблема с регулярными выражениями в плагине jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, валидация

Для валидации форм использую плагин jquery.validate. К функционалу плагина я добавил регулярку проверки имени.

```
$.validator.addMethod("name", function( value, element ) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /[а-яё]/i.test( value );
});
```

Но возникла проблема, при вводе, например, 123Александр, плагин не выдаёт ошибку, т.е регулярка не срабатывает.

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            name: true
        }
    }
});
```

Как решить проблему ввода корректного имени, чтобы не было таких ошибок?

Comment: Очень даже "срабатывает", ведь эта регулярка вернет True при нахождении 1 русской буквы. Вам нужно `/^[а-яё]+$/i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/[а-яё]/i` возваращает *true* при нахождении одной русской буквы в строке. Если необходима валидация *целой* строки, т.е. все символы в строке должны являться русскими буквами, используйте

```
/^[а-яё]+$/i
```

Где:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[а-яё]+` - 1 и более русских букв
- `$` - конец строки
- `/i` - модификатор, активирующий нечувствительность выражения к регистру символов.

Демо:

```js
var r  = /^[а-яё]+$/i;
console.log(r.test("Александр"));
console.log(r.test("123Александр"));
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснения!